# Phabricator Image Upload Failure

Tags: apache, phabricator

We recently moved to a new server and now whenever we try to use the drag and drop upload tool with images (other files work fine!), we are presented with an Upload Failure text and a long string of code. I should also note that uploading directly with the "Files" app works fine, however, Pholio only works using the drag and drop facility. Does anyone know where to start in fixing this?

Upload Failure
banner.jpg

```
Server responded: <!DOCTYPE html><html><head><meta charset="UTF-8" /><title>404 Not Found</title><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no" /><link rel="mask-icon" color="#3D4B67" href="http://phabricator.shopmassive.com/res/phabricator/e132a80f/rsrc/favicons/mask-icon.svg" /><link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="http://phabricator.shopmassive.com/res/phabricator/2d061a11/rsrc/favicons/apple-touch-icon-76x76.png" /><link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="120x120" href="http://phabricator.shopmassive.com/res/phabricator/0d1543c7/rsrc/favicons/apple-touch-icon-120x120.png" /><link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="152x152" href="http://phabricator.shopmassive.com/res/phabricator/65905ecd/rsrc/favicons/apple-touch-icon-152x152.png" /><link id="favicon" rel="shortcut icon" href="http://phabricator.shopmassive.com/res/phabricator/cdb11121/rsrc/favicons/favicon.ico" /><meta name="referrer" content="never" /><script type="text/javascript">(top == self) || top.location.replace(self.location.href);window.__DEV__=0;</script><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://phabricator.shopmassive.com/res/defaultX/phabricator/19f6f61f/core.pkg.css" /><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://phabricator.shopmassive.com/res/defaultX/phabricator/ff161f2d/conpherence.pkg.css" /><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://phabricator.shopmassive.com/res/defaultX/phabricator/53798a6d/rsrc/css/aphront/dark-console.css" /><script type="text/javascript" src="http://phabricator.shopmassive.com/res/defaultX/phabricator/3010e992/rsrc/externals/javelin/core/init.js"></script></head><body class="device-desktop platform-windows phui-theme-blindigo"><div class="main-page-frame" id="main-page-frame"><div id="phabricator-standard-page" class="phabricator-standard-page"><div class="phabricator-main-menu phabricator-main-menu-background" id="UQ0_1"><a class="phabricator-main-menu-search-button phabricator-expand-application-menu" data-sigil="jx-toggle-class" data-meta="0_1"><span class="phabricator-menu-button-icon phui-icon-view phui-font-fa fa-search" id="UQ0_8"></span></a><a class="phabricator-main-menu-brand" href="/"><span class="aural-only">Home</span><span class="phabricator-main-menu-eye" style="background-size: 40px 40px; background-position: 0 0; background-image: url(http://phabricator.shopmassive.com/file/data/f5t64ldtmfnztdheq6on/PHID-FILE-c4pvtyovack7mf5msout/logo)"></span><span class="phabricator-wordmark">Shopmassive</span></a><div class="visual-only phabricator-main-menu-alerts" aria-hidden="true"><a href="/notification/" class="alert-notifications" id="UQ0_7"><span class="phabricator-main-menu-alert-icon phui-icon-view phui-font-fa fa-bell" data-sigil="menu-icon"></span><span id="UQ0_5" class="phabricator-main-menu-alert-count">0</span></a><a href="/conpherence/" class="alert-notifications" id="UQ0_2"><span class="phabricator-main-menu-message-icon phui-icon-view phui-font-fa fa-comments" data-sigil="menu-icon"></span><span id="UQ0_3" class="phabricator-main-menu-message-count">0</span></a></div><span class="aural-only">No messages. No notifications.</span><ul class="phui-list-view phabricator-search-menu"><li class="phui-list-item-view phui-list-item-type-link phabricator-main-menu-search"><div class=""><form action="/search/" method="POST"><input type="hidden" name="__csrf__" value="B@py3xka338ef0818aea0f594d" /><input type="hidden" name="__form__" value="1" /><div class="phabricator-main-menu-search-container"><input type="text" name="query" id="UQ0_9" autocomplete="off" /><button id="UQ0_36" class="phui-icon-view phui-font-fa fa-search"><button class="button dropdown has-icon phabricator-main-menu-search-dropdown" id="UQ0_37" data-sigil="global-search-dropdown" data-meta="0_2"><span class="visual-only phui-icon-view phui-font-fa fa-globe" data-sigil="global-search-dropdown-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span><div class="phui-button-text"></div><span class="caret"></span></button><input type="hidden" name="search:scope" value="all" data-sigil="global-search-dropdown-input" /><input type="hidden" id="UQ0_38" name="search:application" data-sigil="global-search-dropdown-app" /><span class="aural-only">Search</span></button><input type="hidden" name="search:primary" value="true" /><div id="UQ0_35" class="phabricator-main-menu-search-target"></div></div></form></div></li></ul><div id="UQ0_6" class="phabricator-notification-menu" style="display: none;" data-sigil="phabricator-notification-menu"></div><div id="UQ0_4" class="phabricator-notification-menu" style="display: none;" data-sigil="phabricator-notification-menu"></div><a class=" phabricator-core-user-menu" href="/p/shanemcgrath/" id="UQ0_20"><span style="background-image: url(http://phabricator.shopmassive.com/file/data/oengvrw7w3hyx62cnmco/PHID-FILE-xjlvrjeqdpdmestdw3gn/profile);" class="visual-only phui-icon-view phuihead-small" aria-hidden="true"></span><div class="phui-button-text"></div><span class="caret"></span></a><a class=" phabricator-core-user-menu" href="#" data-sigil="phui-dropdown-menu" data-meta="0_3"><span class="visual-only phui-icon-view phui-font-fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></span><div class="phui-button-text"></div><span class="caret"></span></a></div><div id="phabricator-standard-page-body" class="phabricator-standard-page-body"><div id="darkconsole" class="dark-console" style="display: none;" data-console-key="2vrvmsshtn7hyavl7ktc6zx3"></div><form method="POST" class="aphront-dialog-view " role="dialog" data-sigil="jx-dialog"><input type="hidden" name="__csrf__" value="B@py3xka338ef0818aea0f594d" /><input type="hidden" name="__form__" value="1" /><input type="hidden" name="__dialog__" value="1" /><div class="aphront-dialog-head"><div class="phui-header-shell "><h1 class="phui-header-view"><div class="phui-header-row"><div class="phui-header-col2"><span class="phui-header-header">404 Not Found</span></div><div class="phui-header-col3"></div></div></h1></div></div><div class="aphront-dialog-body phabricator-remarkup grouped"><p class="aphront-dialog-view-paragraph">Do not dwell in the past, do not dream of the future, concentrate the mind on the present moment.</p></div><div class="aphront-dialog-tail grouped"><a href="/" class="button grey" name="__cancel__" data-sigil="jx-workflow-button" data-meta="0_0">Focus</a></div></form></div></div><div id="conpherence-durable-column" class="conpherence-durable-column loading " style="display: none;" data-sigil="conpherence-durable-column"><div class="conpherence-durable-column-header grouped" data-sigil="conpherence-minimize-window"><div class="conpherence-durable-column-header-inner"><div class="aphlict-connection-status " id="UQ0_41"><span class="connection-status-text aphlict-connection-status-connecting"><span class="visual-only phui-icon-view phui-font-fa fa-circle-o yellow" aria-hidden="true"></span>Connecting...</span></div><div class="conpherence-durable-column-header-text" data-sigil="conpherence-durable-column-header-text"><span>Conpherence</span></div><ul class="phui-list-view phabricator-application-menu"><li class="phui-list-item-view phui-list-item-type-link phui-list-item-has-icon core-menu-item conpherence-settings-icon" id="UQ0_39" data-sigil="conpherence-settings-menu"><a href="#" class="phui-list-item-href"><span class="aural-only">Room Actions</span><span class="visual-only phui-icon-view phui-font-fa fa-gear phui-list-item-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span><span class="phui-list-item-name visual-only">Room Actions</span></a></li><li class="phui-list-item-view phui-list-item-type-link phui-list-item-has-icon core-menu-item conpherence-minimize-icon" data-sigil="conpherence-minimize-window"><a href="#" class="phui-list-item-href"><span class="aural-only">Minimize Window</span><span class="visual-only phui-icon-view phui-font-fa fa-toggle-down phui-list-item-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span><span class="phui-list-item-name visual-only">Minimize Window</span></a></li></ul><div id="UQ0_40" class="phabricator-main-menu-dropdown phui-list-sidenav conpherence-settings-dropdown" sigil="phabricator-notification-menu" style="display: none"><ul class="phui-list-view "><li class="phui-list-item-view phui-list-item-type-link phui-list-item-has-icon " data-meta="0_4" data-sigil="conpherence-durable-column-header-action"><a href="#" class="phui-list-item-href"><span class="visual-only phui-icon-view phui-font-fa fa-times phui-list-item-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span><span class="phui-list-item-name">Hide Window</span></a></li></ul></div></div></div><div class="conpherence-durable-column-body" data-sigil="conpherence-durable-column-body"><div class="conpherence-durable-column-icon-bar"></div><div class="conpherence-durable-column-main" data-sigil="conpherence-durable-column-main"><div id="conpherence-durable-column-content" class="conpherence-durable-column-frame"><div class="conpherence-durable-column-transactions" data-sigil="conpherence-durable-column-transactions">Loading...</div></div></div></div></div></div><script type="text/javascript" src="http://phabricator.shopmassive.com/res/defaultX/phabricator/1475bd91/core.pkg.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="http://phabricator.shopmassive.com/res/defaultX/phabricator/1f9a31bc/darkconsole.pkg.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="http://phabricator.shopmassive.com/res/defaultX/phabricator/c8e1ffe3/rsrc/js/core/darkconsole/DarkLog.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="http://phabricator.shopmassive.com/res/defaultX/phabricator/c48cccdd/rsrc/js/core/darkconsole/DarkMessage.js"></script><script type="text/javascript">JX.Stratcom.mergeData(0, [[],{"map":{"UQ0_1":"phabricator-search-menu-expanded","UQ0_8":"menu-icon-selected"}},{"items":[{"name":"Search"},{"icon":"fa-globe","name":"All Documents","value":"all"},{"icon":"fa-dot-circle-o","name":"Current Application","value":"application"},{"name":"Saved Queries"},{"icon":"fa-certificate","name":"Open Documents","value":"open"},{"icon":"fa-certificate","name":"Open Tasks","value":"open-tasks"},{"name":"More Options"},{"icon":"fa-search-plus","name":"Advanced Search","href":"\/search\/query\/advanced\/"},{"icon":"fa-book","name":"User Guide: Search","href":"https:\/\/secure.phabricator.com\/diviner\/find\/?name=Search+User+Guide&type=article&jump=1"}],"icon":"fa-globe","value":"all"},{"items":"\u003cul class=\"phabricator-action-list-view \"\u003e\u003cli id=\"UQ0_11\" class=\"phabricator-action-view phabricator-action-view-href phabricator-action-view-type-link\" style=\"\"\u003e\u003ca href=\"\/maniphest\/task\/edit\/form\/default\/\" class=\"phabricator-action-view-item\"\u003eCreate Task\u003c\/a\u003e\u003c\/li\u003e\u003cli id=\"UQ0_13\" class=\"phabricator-action-view phabricator-action-view-href phabricator-action-view-type-link\" style=\"\"\u003e\u003ca href=\"\/project\/edit\/form\/default\/\" class=\"phabricator-action-view-item\"\u003eCreate Project\u003c\/a\u003e\u003c\/li\u003e\u003cli id=\"UQ0_15\" class=\"phabricator-action-view phabricator-action-view-href phabricator-action-view-type-link\" style=\"\"\u003e\u003ca href=\"\/diffusion\/edit\/form\/default\/\" class=\"phabricator-action-view-item\"\u003eCreate Repository\u003c\/a\u003e\u003c\/li\u003e\u003cli id=\"UQ0_17\" class=\"phabricator-action-view phabricator-action-view-type-divider\" style=\"\"\u003e\u003cspan class=\"phabricator-action-view-item\"\u003e\u003c\/span\u003e\u003c\/li\u003e\u003cli id=\"UQ0_19\" class=\"phabricator-action-view phabricator-action-view-href\" style=\"\"\u003e\u003ca href=\"\/favorites\/menu\/configure\/\" class=\"phabricator-action-view-item\"\u003eEdit Favorites\u003c\/a\u003e\u003c\/li\u003e\u003c\/ul\u003e"},{"action":"hide_column"}]); JX.onload(function(){JX.initBehaviors({"refresh-csrf":[{"tokenName":"__csrf__","header":"X-Phabricator-Csrf","viaHeader":"X-Phabricator-Via","current":"B@py3xka338ef0818aea0f594d"}],"dark-console":[{"uri":"Main Request","selected":null,"visible":null,"headers":[]}],"history-install":[]})}); JX.onload(function(){JX.initBehaviors({"workflow":[],"detect-timezone":[{"offset":-540,"uri":"\/settings\/timezone\/","message":"Your browser timezone setting differs from the timezone setting in your profile, click to reconcile.","ignoreKey":"time.offset.ignore","ignore":null}],"setup-check-https":[{"server_https":false,"doc_name":"See Documentation","doc_href":"https:\/\/secure.phabricator.com\/diviner\/find\/?name=Configuring+a+Preamble+Script&type=article&jump=1","message":"Phabricator thinks you are using HTTP, but your client is conviced that it is using HTTPS. This is a serious misconfiguration with subtle, but significant, consequences."}],"lightbox-attachments":[{"lightbox_id":"UQ0_0","downloadForm":"\u003cform action=\"#\" method=\"POST\" class=\"lightbox-download-form\" id=\"lightbox-download-form\" data-sigil=\"download lightbox-download-submit\"\u003e\u003cinput type=\"hidden\" name=\"__csrf__\" value=\"B@py3xka338ef0818aea0f594d\" \/\u003e\u003cinput type=\"hidden\" name=\"__form__\" value=\"1\" \/\u003e\u003ca class=\"lightbox-download phui-icon-circle hover-green\" href=\"#\"\u003e\u003cspan class=\"visual-only phui-icon-view phui-font-fa fa-download phui-icon-circle-icon\" aria-hidden=\"true\"\u003e\u003c\/span\u003e\u003c\/a\u003e\u003c\/form\u003e"}],"aphront-form-disable-on-submit":[],"toggle-class":[],"phabricator-gesture":[],"device":[],"high-security-warning":[{"show":false,"uri":"\/auth\/session\/downgrade\/","message":"Your session is in high security mode. When you finish using it, click here to leave."}],"aphlict-dropdown":[{"bubbleID":"UQ0_2","countID":"UQ0_3","dropdownID":"UQ0_4","loadingText":"Loading...","uri":"\/conpherence\/panel\/","countType":"messages","countNumber":0,"unreadClass":"message-unread","favicon":"http:\/\/phabricator.shopmassive.com\/res\/phabricator\/cdb11121\/rsrc\/favicons\/favicon.ico","message_favicon":"http:\/\/phabricator.shopmassive.com\/res\/phabricator\/115bc010\/rsrc\/favicons\/favicon-message.ico","mention_favicon":"http:\/\/phabricator.shopmassive.com\/res\/phabricator\/1fdd0fa4\/rsrc\/favicons\/favicon-mention.ico"},{"bubbleID":"UQ0_7","countID":"UQ0_5","dropdownID":"UQ0_6","loadingText":"Loading...","uri":"\/notification\/panel\/","countType":"notifications","countNumber":0,"unreadClass":"alert-unread","favicon":"http:\/\/phabricator.shopmassive.com\/res\/phabricator\/cdb11121\/rsrc\/favicons\/favicon.ico","message_favicon":"http:\/\/phabricator.shopmassive.com\/res\/phabricator\/115bc010\/rsrc\/favicons\/favicon-message.ico","mention_favicon":"http:\/\/phabricator.shopmassive.com\/res\/phabricator\/1fdd0fa4\/rsrc\/favicons\/favicon-mention.ico"},{"bubbleID":"UQ0_39","dropdownID":"UQ0_40","local":true,"containerDivID":"conpherence-durable-column"}],"phabricator-keyboard-shortcuts":[{"helpURI":"\/help\/keyboardshortcut\/","searchID":"UQ0_9","pht":{"\/":"Give keyboard focus to the search box.","?":"Show keyboard shortcut help for the current page."}}],"phui-dropdown-menu":[],"user-menu":[{"menuID":"UQ0_20","menu":{"items":"\u003cul class=\"phabricator-action-list-view \"\u003e\u003cli id=\"UQ0_22\" class=\"phabricator-action-view\" style=\"\"\u003e\u003cspan class=\"phabricator-action-view-item\"\u003e\u003cul class=\"phui-oi-list-view phui-oi-list-flush phui-oi-list-simple phabricator-core-user-profile-object\"\u003e\u003cli class=\"phui-oi phui-oi-no-bar phui-oi-with-image phui-oi-standard\"\u003e\u003cdiv class=\"phui-oi-frame\"\u003e\u003cdiv class=\"phui-oi-frame-content\"\u003e\u003cdiv class=\"phui-oi-image\" style=\"background-image: url(http:\/\/phabricator.shopmassive.com\/file\/data\/oengvrw7w3hyx62cnmco\/PHID-FILE-xjlvrjeqdpdmestdw3gn\/profile)\"\u003e\u003c\/div\u003e\u003cdiv class=\"phui-oi-content-box\"\u003e\u003cdiv class=\"phui-oi-table\"\u003e\u003cdiv class=\"phui-oi-table-row\"\u003e\u003cdiv class=\"phui-oi-col1\"\u003e\u003cdiv class=\"phui-oi-name\"\u003e\u003cspan data-sigil=\"slippery\"\u003e\u003cspan class=\"phui-oi-objname\"\u003eShane McGrath\u003c\/span\u003e \u003cdiv class=\"phui-oi-link\"\u003e\u003c\/div\u003e\u003c\/span\u003e\u003c\/div\u003e\u003cdiv class=\"phui-oi-content\"\u003e\u003cdiv class=\"phui-oi-subhead\"\u003eshanemcgrath\u003c\/div\u003e\u003c\/div\u003e\u003c\/div\u003e\u003c\/div\u003e\u003c\/div\u003e\u003c\/div\u003e\u003c\/div\u003e\u003c\/div\u003e\u003c\/li\u003e\u003c\/ul\u003e\u003c\/span\u003e\u003c\/li\u003e\u003cli id=\"UQ0_24\" class=\"phabricator-action-view phabricator-action-view-type-divider\" style=\"\"\u003e\u003cspan class=\"phabricator-action-view-item\"\u003e\u003c\/span\u003e\u003c\/li\u003e\u003cli id=\"UQ0_26\" class=\"phabricator-action-view phabricator-action-view-href\" style=\"\"\u003e\u003ca href=\"\/p\/shanemcgrath\/\" class=\"phabricator-action-view-item\"\u003eProfile\u003c\/a\u003e\u003c\/li\u003e\u003cli id=\"UQ0_28\" class=\"phabricator-action-view phabricator-action-view-href\" style=\"\"\u003e\u003ca href=\"\/settings\/user\/shanemcgrath\/\" class=\"phabricator-action-view-item\"\u003eSettings\u003c\/a\u003e\u003c\/li\u003e\u003cli id=\"UQ0_30\" class=\"phabricator-action-view phabricator-action-view-href\" style=\"\"\u003e\u003ca href=\"\/people\/manage\/1\/\" class=\"phabricator-action-view-item\"\u003eManage\u003c\/a\u003e\u003c\/li\u003e\u003cli id=\"UQ0_32\" class=\"phabricator-action-view phabricator-action-view-type-divider\" style=\"\"\u003e\u003cspan class=\"phabricator-action-view-item\" data-sigil=\"logout-item\"\u003e\u003c\/span\u003e\u003c\/li\u003e\u003cli id=\"UQ0_34\" class=\"phabricator-action-view phabricator-action-view-href action-item-red\" style=\"\"\u003e\u003ca href=\"\/logout\/\" class=\"phabricator-action-view-item\" data-sigil=\"workflow logout-item\"\u003eLog Out shanemcgrath\u003c\/a\u003e\u003c\/li\u003e\u003c\/ul\u003e"}}],"phabricator-search-typeahead":[{"id":"UQ0_35","input":"UQ0_9","button":"UQ0_36","selectorID":"UQ0_37","applicationID":"UQ0_38","defaultApplicationIcon":"fa-dot-circle-o","appScope":"application","src":"\/typeahead\/class\/PhabricatorSearchDatasource\/","limit":10,"placeholder":"Search","scopeUpdateURI":"\/settings\/adjust\/?key=search-scope"}],"quicksand-blacklist":[{"patterns":["\/phame\/live\/.*","\/conpherence\/.*","\/Z\\d+","\/file\/data\/.*"]}],"durable-column":[{"visible":false,"minimize":false,"visibleURI":"\/settings\/adjust\/?key=conpherence-column","minimizeURI":"\/settings\/adjust\/?key=conpherence-minimize-column","quicksandConfig":{"title":"404 Not Found","bodyClasses":"device-desktop platform-windows phui-theme-blindigo","aphlictDropdownData":[{"isInstalled":true,"countType":"notifications","count":0,"rawCount":0},{"isInstalled":true,"countType":"messages","count":0,"rawCount":0}],"globalDragAndDrop":false,"hisecWarningConfig":{"show":false,"uri":"\/auth\/session\/downgrade\/","message":"Your session is in high security mode. When you finish using it, click here to leave."},"consoleConfig":{"uri":"Main Request","selected":null,"visible":null,"headers":[]},"applicationClass":null,"applicationSearchIcon":null,"helpItems":null,"pageObjects":[],"subscriptions":["PHID-USER-lmfdmv4wlorcekiihcu4"]}}],"aphlict-status":[{"nodeID":"UQ0_41","pht":{"setup":"Setting Up Client","open":"Connected","closed":"Disconnected"},"icon":{"open":{"icon":"fa-circle","color":"green"},"setup":{"icon":"fa-circle","color":"yellow"},"closed":{"icon":"fa-circle","color":"red"}}}],"aphlict-listen":[{"websocketURI":"ws:\/\/phabricator.shopmassive.com:22280\/","pageObjects":[],"subscriptions":["PHID-USER-lmfdmv4wlorcekiihcu4"]}]})});</script></body></html>
```